# Dependency injection create instance

Tags: java, dependency-injection

Let we have class

```
public class MessageB implements Message{
    private String msg;
    public MessageB(){ };
    public MessageB(String msg){
        this.msg=msg;
    }

    @Override
    public String get(){
        return "Message B";
    }
}
```

and HttpServlet

```
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Inject private MessageB message;

    public void doGet(HttpServlet request, HttpServlet response) throws IOException{
        response.getWriter().write(message.get());
    } 
}
```

In official tutorial said that

```
CDI runtime looks for classes that implements the Message inteface, find the MessageB
```

class, create a new instance of it, and inject it into the servlet at runtime.

How at runtime we know what contructor must be invoked?

Comment: I don't know CDI well, but It seems that you gave him the instruction at the annotation @Inject, so it'll inject automatically on servlet creation, without using constructor. If you don't know, depedency injection is not only about injecting on constructors, it can be in any way.

Comment: When CDI container create the object of CDI bean MessageB that time bean constructor is called. like java normal constructor You can add system.out.print statement inside bean constructor, you can inject more than one class or servlet or in managed bean ejb

Comment: Correct your interface implements Message not the implements Message()

Comment: @user435187 Thus CDI bean also must have only default constructor?

Comment: By default  CDI container look for the default (no arguments) constructor and use it to create the bean instance. You can define your explicit constructor inside bean that is annotated with with @Inject annotation then CDI will call this constructor.  only one constructor should be annotated with one inject annotation, if container finds  more than one constructor annotated with inject annotation in a class then container will throw error